# HTA call CWD from VBScript variable in HTML form input text box

Tags: javascript, variables, input, vbscript, hta

I have an input text box which I would like to display the current working directory on load.

```vb
<script language = "VBScript">
Dim cwd 
cwd = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
Dim Master
Dim Master1
Dim folderdefault
folderdefault = cwd

Sub ChooseSaveFolder
    strStartDir = ""
    userselections.txtFile.value = PickFolder(strStartDir)
End Sub 

Function PickFolder(strStartDir)
    Dim SA, F
    Set SA = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set F = SA.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0, strStartDir)
    If (Not F Is Nothing) Then
        PickFolder = F.Items.Item.path
    End If
    Set F = Nothing
    Set SA = Nothing
End Function 

Sub CheckMaster
    Master = userselections.txtFile.value
    If userselections.txtFile.value ="" Then
        MsgBox "No folder selected." & folderdefault
    Else
        ' Alert "Default folder is now : " & vbCrLf & Master & vbCrLf & cwd
        MsgBox "Default folder selected:" & vbCrLf & folderdefault & vbCrLf & "Master=" & Master & vbCrLf & "cwd=" & cwd
    End If        
End Sub
</script>
```

HTML call the variable cwd and auto fill the text area:

```html
<form name="userselections">
    <input type="button" value = "Select Folder" onClick="ChooseSaveFolder()" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="run_button"  onClick="vbscript:CheckMaster"><br>
    <input type="text" name="txtFile" class="folder" value=cwd />
</form>
```

The "value" part of the input text just displays literally "cwd" in the text field. I am not certain how to call the VBScript variable cwd and put that in the text area. I think it's something similar to:

```vb
document.userselections.txtFile.value = folderdefault
```

If JavaScript can call the VBScript variable, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="vbscript">
    Option Explicit
    Dim cwd
    cwd = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    window.alert(cwd);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When saved with the `.hta` extension and run, it displays the current folder of the HTA.

---

You should be able to do the following from VBScript:

```
document.userselections.txtFile.value = folderdefault
```

but you have to make sure that the form elements have already been loaded. The simplest way for you to do that, would be to include another script element with this code, at the end of the `body` element:

```
<script language="vbscript">
    document.userselections.txtFile.value = folderdefault
</script>
```

Comment: I can't get it to work!Can you kindly show me an example? Intergrate it with the above code? I would  be very much appreciated!

Comment: @PCTipsnTricks I'm sorry for the delay; I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PCTipsnTricks _I can't get it to work_ -- Could you elaborate? Are you getting some kind of error? Is it just not setting the value?

Answer (score 0):

add this anywhere on your vbscript:

```
Sub Window_onLoad
    document.getElementsByName("txtFile")[0].value = cwd
End Sub
```